# Something wrong with Documentation interface

Tags: support, documentation

There is [an article](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/17076/how-to-add-image-and-other-information-into-database-using-pdo-to-prevent-it-fr#t=201608250953043267711) which I wanted to remove as irrelevant to the section and to its own title.

But out of two attempts I failed with both.

First time it seems I deleted a topic that was requested for improvement. Can it be restored? (Sorry, I don't understand how to link to it)

Second time I asked for improvement for a topic which is OK and my request is irrelevant. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/275/2685
Can I retract my request?

Although I admit it's my fault, something should be done to the interface to make it fool-proof against such fools as I am. The interface, with all the articles stuffed in a single page is just confusing. And when you are in not by direct link by by some action link (like viewing an improvement request) it become even more confusing. And god forbid you from hitting a "Back" button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dismissed the misplaced improvement request. I'm not sure if you could've done that yourself.

The deleted example, on the other hand, can be reverted.

If you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/275) of the topic, you can click **[View Topic]** for a previous revision.
If you then click **[Create draft rolling back to this version]**, you can rollback your edit.

The "revision history"-link is found at the bottom of a topic:

> [image]

Comment: There is a "Dismiss" button under the request, I tried to press that, but it seems it dismisses the notification only. At least the request still remained in the list. Now it's gone, thank you.

Comment: The "Dismiss" button is only for drafts, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for the second pointer as well, now I know how to revert an edit.  though for this particular one I examined the deleted entry and decided to keep it deleted.